# How to get odometry from propeller rotation signals knowing that they can rotate to maximum value?

Tags: ros, odometry, sensor-fusion, rotation

m trying to get Velocity in order to control underwater swarm ROV. I can use the acceleration and to Euler integration but the error will be accumulated over time. As we are having a swarm (many small robots) Im limited with sensors on board. So in order to get more accurate Velocity estimation was thinking of sensor Fusing of IMU and odometry. As don't have any odometry sensors came to some out of the box solution

So as I have access to the motor (thruster- propeller) signals and the robot can move to maximum and constant speed. Means the rotation of the propeller have a maximum limit and when they reach that limit they can maintain that maximum. So was thinking of some mathematical model that can be used to provide me with odometry and than use some of the ROS packages for sensor fission(robot_lokalization orh ector_pose_estimation) to get accurate Velocity.

The propeller revolution curve looks like something like this
[image]

So I need a help in that mathematical model how to get odometry from the motors-thrusters. Any help with that and possible ROS node (C++) implementation?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking - are you trying to count propeller revolutions to get a distance, or are you trying to use propeller speed to get robot speed?

Comment: yes the propeller revolutions to get distance, so the  propeller serves like encoders so can get odometry topic. It require some mathematical modeling for that

Comment: I edit how the propeller revolution curve looks like with a tau inclination.

Comment: What are the axes on the plot? I don't understand what I'm looking at. There are two curves - what are they?

Comment: im not sure but i think is the propeller revolution over time. But anyway can you help how to get odometry (distance) from propeller revolutions, and the ROS node?

Comment: you have to run experiments to learn how the propeller rotation relates to distance travelled of your ROV ... once you have enough data, then you may be able to approximate the distance traveled from propeller rotation data

Comment: I can not run experiments at the moment . I dont have the robot now. Only can do Gazebo Simulation. such as this one https://uuvsimulator.github.io/. So for now i have own fish model and want to use sensor that later will be deployed on the real robot to close the control loop.

Comment: Ok sorry, Finally to get clear im trying to use  propeller speed to get robot speed. So knowing the force to the thrusters , also i know the drag so there is a way to get the speed of the robot

Comment: So what Im aiming is using the Gazebo simulation https://uuvsimulator.github.io/ I can get the Force to the thrusters and using the  propeller speed to get robot speed. Hope now is clear. I can not do any experiments just pure simulation Any help?

Comment: You've got a simulator, so you have perfect knowledge of the vehicle and what it's doing - you should do some testing here to characterize the relationship. Vehicle speed, prop speed, vehicle position, prop rotations, etc. Do it for a variety of speeds and see what looks good. That said, all of this will largely be a waste of time if your simulator doesn't accurately reflect the motion characteristics of your actual vehicle.